# Can't publish .NET MAUI android apps

Tags: android, .net, maui, .net-maui

I've been working on an app in .NET MAUI and now after finishing it I realized I couldn't publish it, it seems like I can't even publish the .NET MAUI default app.

I created a Keystore using

`keytool -genkey -v -keystore myapp.keystore -alias MyAppkey -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000`

and added the reference to the Keystore file and implemented it in the .csproj
then changed debug mode to release, build the project and finally used this to publish

`dotnet publish -f:net6.0-android -c:Release /p:AndroidSigningKeyPass=password /p:AndroidSigningStorePass=password`

and it throws this error
[[BT : 1.8.1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4rhJ.jpg)

Comment: I don't think this is an issue with Archive, Have you tried building your app in release once?

Comment: Yes i did
And that's what i got

Comment: So its a Compile issue?

Comment: I have no idea
I just know it works completely fine while debugging

Comment: But when i switch to release and want to publish i get this error
One time it worked and gave me an APK file
I installed that on my phone
And after opening it

Comment: It just crashed
I couldn't open it at all:')

Comment: I have it on GitHub

Comment: I can give u a link

Comment: Give me sometime i will look into this :)

Comment: https://github.com/mobinbeiran/UnitConverter.git

Comment: any update on this issue?